# BluePrism Running An Excel Macro with User input

Tags: blueprism, rpa

Right now I have an issue with an Excel Macro where it takes an input from the user.

Current process is: Create Instance -> Open Workbook -> Run Macro
The process is stuck at "Run Macro" and is unable to be "detached" for further actions.

Any tips and tricks?

screen shots:
[macro code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZgRq.png)

[macro requiring user input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WL78d.png)

Comment: Please provide a sample of your code, example of expected inputs and desired results, and more information about your specific problems and questions.

Comment: What is supposed to happen after the macro? as it stands, it appears you just get BP to open and activate a worksheet and hand over to a VBA macro. Also, you do not specify where is it that it gets stuck - is it after entering this password in the VBA inputbox? or is it after the macro is supposed to have finished running and returned control of the workbook to BP? what is BP supposed to do in the next stage? are you getting any error messages given by BP? Can you show the VBA code here?

Comment: You could try adding this after the first line of VBA and before end/exit sub: Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, when you're running excel VBA code, then the BluePrism will wait until the code will be finished.

That means that you should not run a code like that using BluePrism, as it's sure way to lock your process. The process will wait for VBA to finish, and VBA will wait for user.

If you'd like to interact with interface that VBA presents, then I can advise you one of the following things:

- Rebuild the VBA code, so that the parameters are passed from the BluePrism and so that there are no pop-up windows
- Start the VBA code using any spying technologies - for example create a UI button that will be clicked by BluePrism

Comment: +1 - Parametrize you macro to take a function argument, and if necessary create a credential in System Credentials, for automatic input(WITHOUT the VBA popup). Depending on your implementation/practices, you should be looking to minimize user typing input.

Comment: The Excel sheet is provided & developed by the client, looks like the only way to start the macro without getting locked is by spying for the button.

Answer (score 3):

By default this method is not available in MS Excel VBO. You need to extend the VBO for this.

Below are the steps to extend/append the functionality you needed:

1. Open MS Excel VBO
2. Duplicate the action call "Run Macro" which by default available in VBO
3. Change the name of action which is newly created
4. Modify the start parameter for newly created action (Note: This action should also get the input parameter to hold the values)
5. Double click on code stage and pass the input parameter for the code stage.
6. Click on Code tab --> modify the code as below:

   - lets consider, you need pass the 2 variable to macro then
   - Modify the statement : `GetInstance(Handle).Run(Macro_Name,param1,param2)`
7. click on ok - > publish and save the newly created action
8. Use the newly created action in your process.